# To rotate X (or) Y axis of rect ?

Tags: svg, highcharts

I know that, in svg, if i want to rotate a shapes:

```
    transform="rotate(deg cx cy)"
```

but is possible to rotate  X axis or Y axis of shape ?

Comment: What does "rotate X axis" mean?

Comment: At the bottom of page http://www.svgopen.org/2008/papers/86-Achieving_3D_Effects_with_SVG/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: no.  SVG is a 2D graphics format.  The shapes in an SVG are restricted to 2D transforms.  If you want to get the effect of perspective or other 3D transforms, you have to simulate it by morphing the shape.

However, it **is** possible to apply a CSS 3D transform to the **whole** SVG element, just as you can any other HTML element.

Comment: but is possible to use CSS 3D transform inner svg element ?

Comment: No.  Only the outermost `<svg>` element.

Comment: Thanks Paul, finally... do you know that if also in highcharts is impossible to use 3d transform or CSS 3D transform ?

Comment: No.  I haven't used Highcharts.  Sorry.